# Xmlstarlet select String+number for update

Tags: regex, xml, linux, xpath, xmlstarlet

I want to update an element in my xml-File, with some dynamic names.
The name (paraName) is always GLOBPARA followed by a number, like you can see in the following example. These are the elements I want to change the value.

The file is also filled with some elements, which are also starting with an GLOBPARA, but have no simple number following. These elements I don't want to change.

With the following command I can change every element, which has a GLOBPARA in the name. Including the unwanted ones.
    xmlstarlet ed --update "//globPara[contains(paramName, 'GLOBPARA')]/paramValue" -v "100" test.xml

**Question:**
How do I change only the ones, containing a String (GLOBPARA) and some random Numbers?

Before:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<container>
  <dataList>
    <globPara>
      <paramName>GLOBPARA260</paramName>
      <paramValue>0</paramValue>
    </globPara>
    <globPara>
      <paramName>GLOBPARAMON_BAD_TEST_18_1_SGB_IV</paramName>
      <paramValue>2555</paramValue>
    </globPara>
  </dataList>
</container>
```

Wanted result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<container>
  <dataList>
    <globPara>
      <paramName>GLOBPARA260</paramName>
      <paramValue>100</paramValue>
    </globPara>
    <globPara>
      <paramName>GLOBPARAMON_BAD_TEST_18_1_SGB_IV</paramName>
      <paramValue>2555</paramValue>
    </globPara>
  </dataList>
</container>
```

I tried it with the regex d+, but it didn't work.

```
xmlstarlet ed --update "//globPara[contains(paramName, 'GLOBPARA[\d+]')]/paramValue" -v "100" test.xml
```

Comment: Probably you will have to spell out the alternatives, `"//globPara[contains(paramName, 'GLOBPARA0') or contains(paramName, 'GLOBPARA1') or contains(paramName, 'GLOBPARA2') or contains(paramName, 'GLOBPARA3') or contains(paramName, 'GLOBPARA4') or contains(paramName, 'GLOBPARA5') or contains(paramName, 'GLOBPARA6') or contains(paramName, 'GLOBPARA7') or contains(paramName, 'GLOBPARA8') or contains(paramName, 'GLOBPARA9')]/paramValue"`

Comment: Sadly the numbers are not in line (example of the first one: 101, 2, 260, 3, 301, 302, 305, 208, ....), are quite huge in numbers (around 150) and can change for each release we receive. So some regex would be nice ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below XPath

```
//globPara[number(substring-after(paramName, 'GLOBPARA'))>=0]/paramValue
```

This will return you `paramValue` of `globPara` node that contains `paraName` child with text in format `GLOBPARAXXX` where `XXX` is *ANY* positive number